# Separate compilation C++ ROS

Tags: ros, c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !

I have a *main_test.cpp* file which include the *functions_test.h* file whose the definitions are contained in the *functions_test.cpp* file.
Here the procedure that I followed:

- I placed *functions_test.h* to this location: *include/my_package_name/*
- I placed *functions_test.cpp* and *main_test.cpp* to this location: *src/*
- I added in the CMakeLists.txt the following lines:

  include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})<br/>
  add_executable(main_test src/main_test.cpp src/functions_test.cpp)<br/>
  target_link_libraries(main_test ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

My problem is when I run *catkin_make*, the prototypes of the functions in the *functions_test.h* file are successfully seen but not the definitions of the functions inside the *functions_test.cpp* file and therefore I get an *undefined reference* error.

I don't know what I missed. If someone can help me, I will be grateful,
lfr

I did some changes, but I still have the same error.
Here my new CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(my_package_name)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
actionlib
move_base_msgs
roscpp
std_msgs
tf
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES functions_test
)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_library(functions_test src/functions_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(functions_test ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_executable(main_test src/main_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main_test functions_test)
```

Here the complete error message:

```
CMakeFiles/main_test.dir/src/main_test.cpp.o: In function `main':
main_test.cpp:(.text+0x22d): undefined reference to `void nav_api::execute_checkpoints<double, bool>(std::vector<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal_<std::allocator<void> > > > (*)(double, bool), double, bool)'
main_test.cpp:(.text+0x2da): undefined reference to `void nav_api::execute_checkpoints<double, double, bool>(std::vector<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal_<std::allocator<void> > > > (*)(double, double, bool), double, double, bool)'
main_test.cpp:(.text+0x383): undefined reference to `void nav_api::execute_checkpoints<double, bool>(std::vector<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal_<std::allocator<void> > > > (*)(double, bool), double, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/********/catkin_ws/devel/lib/my_package_name/main_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [my_package_name/CMakeFiles/main_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

The prototypes of the concerned functions is below:

```
template <typename P0>
void execute_checkpoints(std::vector <move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal>(*order)(P0), P0 p0);
template <typename P1, typename P2>
void execute_checkpoints(std::vector <move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal>(*order)(P1, P2), P1 p1, P2 p2);
template <typename P1, typename P2, typename P3>
void execute_checkpoints(std::vector <move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal>(*order)(P1, P2, P3), P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3);
```

I want to notify that the code works correctly when I include directly the *functions_test.cpp* at the beginning of *main_test.cpp*. But I know that it is a bad solution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235581/separate-compilation-c++-ros/) by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2016-05-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2016-05-30**:
Everything looks good to me. Can you please post your complete CMakeLists.txt?

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-05-31**:
I updated the question (with the new CMakeLists.txt)

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2016-06-06**:
In your question you write that you do `add_executable(main_test src/main_test.cpp src/functions_test.cpp)` which is correct. In your `CMakeLists.txt` you don't do this. You write that you updated your file, was it this what you updated?

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-06-06**:
Yes, it was what I updated because it didn't works and I wanted to try what spmaniato advises in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !

I found my mistake. I forgot that templates functions must be defined inside the header file. It works properly now.
Thank you to all of you for helping me.

lfr.

---

Originally posted by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) with karma: 201 on 2016-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0